# Isometries between spherical space forms

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $S^n/\Gamma_i\,(i=1,2)$ be a $n$-dimensional spherical space form, where $\Gamma_i \subset SO(n+1)$ is a finite subgroup acting freely on $S^n$.

Suppose $S^n/\Gamma_1$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n/\Gamma_2$, can we show they are isometric?

Comment: A big chunk of the details are in Thurston's "Three-Dimensional Geometry and Topology".  As Igor mentioned, the primary technicality issue is Lens spaces, and that part isn't as developed in Thurston's book.  Bonahon has a lovely proof in that context, and you can also find Bonahon's proof in Hatcher's 3-manifolds notes (on his web page).

Comment: @RyanBudney Thursron's book and Hatcher's notes are about the three dimensional manifolds while the question is for any $n$. I see something missing here.

Comment: De Rham's theorem is for every dimension. For 3d lens spaces there are other proofs, I think.

Comment: Whoops, I just imagined this was the $n=3$ case.  The general case is similar, although the Bonahon proof is particular to $n=3$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, diffeomorphic spherical space forms are isometric. This famous result of Georges de Rham can be found in [de Rham, G.
Complexes à automorphismes et homéomorphie différentiable. 
Ann. Inst. Fourier Grenoble 2 (1950), 51–67 (1951)]. The main tool is Reidemeister's torsion. For lens spaces the result was proved by W. Franz in 1935.

Comment: Is there a more recent reference to this result?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: I wondered the same in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21848/isometry-classification-of-spherical-space-forms and I still do not know the answer (in dimensions $>3$).